# sublime text completion pop up does not move down to the item as I type

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I needed a editor for my python development I decided to go with sublime text 2. Its great and needed a auto completion as in komodo edit. I installed a package control and picked this "SublimeCodeIntel" package. Installed fine and works fine except during the "import module"
for example I want to "import collections"
when I type space bar after import statement, the pop up with all the module comes up but when i start typing it should move down with respect to the letters i am typing, but simply disappears.

some debugging I did was:

- made sure the module I am typing actually exists by scrolling down with in the pop up
- pop up scrolling works fine in other areas like when I try to bring up methods within the module (module.methodName)
- I tried reinstalling and restarting the sublime

some one have idea on this or faced this before?

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: thanks MattDMo Mac OS X 10.6